# Squish on iOS vs Fonemonkey on iOS

Tags: testing

Hi 
I have requested for a version of Squish to try it for iOS automation testing. I am curious to know if there is any one who has tried this earlier. I have been using FoneMonkey till now and I am wondering if the recording functionality of squish as being advertised is the case or if there if some one has done some research comparing Squish and FoneMonkey for iOS device automation testing.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously I'm biased (from froglogic), but yes, Squish for iPhone/iOS offers recording and works in the Simulator and in the device(s)

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Squish and FoneMonkey, and I personally recommend Squish for iOS testing as it provides a test script recording option which is much advanced than FoneMonkey. It provided option for both Object verification and Image verification. Also running on both Simulator and on device becomes simple with just few minor changes to the source of your test app.